# Php Записать куку для конкретного Url?

Tags: php

У меня есть кука которая заполняется при посещении сайта:

```
setcookie("request", "true", time()+3600*87760);
```

Как можно сделать работу куки для конкретных страниц?
Т.е если зашел на site.com/page1 кука записалась и действует на этой странице, на остальных же нет, и т.д со всеми страницами - в общем делаю показ div на каждой страницы только при первом посещении. Можно ли подобное реализовать через куку по url?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php#refsect1-function.setcookie-description...... четвертый параметр.......`path - 
Путь к директории на сервере, из которой будут доступны cookie. Если задать '/', cookie будут доступны во всем домене domain. Если задать '/foo/', cookie будут доступны только из директории /foo/ и всех ее поддиректорий (например, /foo/bar/) домена domain. По умолчанию значением является текущая директория, в которой cookie устанавливается.`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , а если нужна страница именно по get параметру?

Comment: Можно воспользоваться примером: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9369974/6104996

Comment: Тогда назовите кук по-другому. COOCIE_FOR_GET_BLA_BLA_BLA. Только нафига, если есть get